# Regex for beginning of string not ending with faq/

Tags: regex

I'm using regex to filter domains and subsets of domains.

this one works for everything from example.com:

```
^https?://www.example.com/
```

I would like to exclude every item that is from the path /faq. I tried both,

```
^https?://www.zenconomy.se/[^faq]
^https?://www.zenconomy.se/[!faq]
```

but neither worked.

Comment: You need to use a negative lookahead

Comment: Square brackets are for character sets, not strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is one which might help. Adding `(?!faq)` this to your pattern.

Comment: The negative lookahead looks for this patterns and if matches discard the input.